# In magento i need to display a logo image in selected product page

Tags: magento

In magento i  need to display a logo image in product page and have to restrict its display for certain products using attribute from admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create one attribute [Ex-logo display?]with drop-down and assign to attribute set**

*set option value yes and no* and go to the manage product and *`set to yes` in product to 
display logo*

and in `view.phtml` **put condition** `$_product->getData('logo_display')==1` **then display

your logo image**

otherwise not

Comment: Where i need to upload the image either through admin or else through code@Keyur Shah

Comment: through code you have to add image

Comment: Is this syntax <?php if ($_product->getData('logo_display')==1:<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>/images/genuine2.png"  alt="" />?> is correct for condition.@Keyur Shah

Comment: yes but your attribute identifier should be logo_display

Comment: if you write another identifier then write another identifier

Comment: Hi i think the syntax is not correct i m getting error if i have implemented this code@Keyur Shah

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45891/discussion-between-user2089987-and-keyur-shah)